# Element available for more groups than one

Tags: django, django-templates

For example I have the button in my template that is available only for stuff:

```
{% if request.user.is_staff %}
<a href="{% url 'unosZanraKnjige' %}" class="button">Add new</a>
{% endif %}
```

I have group created in http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ called "Djelatnici".

Is it possible to make some element (button in this case) available only for specific groups with "OR" (||) condition, something like:

```
{% if request.user.is_staff %} || {% if request.user.is_djelatnici %}
<a href="{% url 'unosZanraKnjige' %}" class="button">Add new</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using [Django Custom Template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)

Something like this:

**my_custom_tag.py**

```py
@register.filter(name='is_my_custom_group')
def is_my_custom_group(user, group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

Then on your template you import this tag and use like this:

**template.html**

```html
{% load is_my_custom_group %}

{% if request.user.is_staff or request.user|is_my_custom_group:'Djelatnici' %}
    <a href="{% url 'unosZanraKnjige' %}" class="button">Add new</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yeah, I did it and it works in the end, thank You. I am not sure why they didn't simplify it when their log and group system is being used.